# Can't get data from the user. The exact code works for one script, but it doesn't work for the other

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get data of user actions. I have two different scripts. The task is slightly different at each one. However, the part where I'm asking for the user name (which I use as a variable for the .csv data's name) and the php code are exactly the same. Though they are the same, I can get data as a csv file from one script but not from the other. What might be the problem here?

JS code for getting the subjectID:

```
        var subjectID = prompt('What is your IU user name? (You need to type in your username so we can grant you credits for your participation. Otherwise, we will not know who you are.)');
    if (subjectID === '' || subjectID == null) {subjectID=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000).toString()};
    jsPsych.data.addProperties({subject_id: subjectID});
```

Function for saving the data:

```
function saveData(name, data){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'write_data2.php'); // 'write_data.php' is the path to the php file described above.
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({filename: name, filedata: data}));
}

jsPsych.init({
    timeline: timeline,
    display_element: 'jspsych-target',
    on_finish: function(){ saveData("IL" + subjectID  + "_data", jsPsych.data.get().csv()); }
})

        
    }
```

the content of write_data2.php file:

```
<?php
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 
// the directory "data" must be writable by the server
$name = "data/".$post_data['filename'].".csv"; 
$data = $post_data['filedata'];
// write the file to disk
file_put_contents($name, $data);
?>
```

finally, I have a folder called "data" at the same directory those scripts are in.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked the PHP error log for any errors, warnings or notices?

Comment: How to check the PHP error log?

Comment: By doing a search... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: This looks bad: `"data/".$post_data['filename'].".csv"` what if i would post `{filename: "../../some_bad_path"}` - hope u are doing some validation